# Quick question on a sequence of differentiable convex function.

Tags: limits, convex-analysis

For a sequence of differentiable convex function $f_n$ converging pointwise to the limit $f$, is it true that then $f$ is differentiable and $\partial_x f_n (x) \to \partial_x f(x)$?

Comment: $[0,1]\ni x\mapsto x^n$

Comment: No. Take $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2+{1 \over n}}$.

Comment: Not even true with uniform convergence, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the answer is no. To add a bit more context, a simple example is the sequence of polynomials $\{f_n(x)=x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $[0,1]$ which converge pointwise to the discontinuous function $$f\colon x\mapsto\begin{cases} 0 &\text{if}\;\;x\in[0,1[;\\ 1 &\text{if}\;\;x=1.\end{cases}$$

Since the resulting limit is non-differentiable, we have to be careful with the statement "$\partial f_n\to \partial f$", because there are multiple distinct notions of "convergence", e.g., pointwise vs graphical. [*Variational Analysis*](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ertr/papers/rtr169-VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf) by Rockafellar and Wets does a good job at discussing these two notions of convergence. It should be noted that, in general, $f_n\to f$ pointwise **does not** imply that $\partial f_n \to \partial f$ pointwise. However, (under some mild conditions) if $f_n \to f$ epigraphically, then $\partial f_n \to \partial f$ graphically.